# php if sql query returns valid result

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm sure this is a simple fix, I want to run a code block if an sql query comes back with a positive result. something like:

```
if($query = mysqli_query($cxn,"[query]"))
{
Code to be executed if the query returns a positive result
}
```

I have tried this format but doesn't work. I'm sure I have done this before but I'm running in to a wall here.

Hope you can help.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a meaningful description of what happened. Did you check for errors? What do you mean by a "positive result"? try `else { print mysqli_error($cxn); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you mean if the query doesn't fail? then:

```
$query = mysqli_query($cxn, "[query]");
if($query !== false) {
  // Code to be executed if the query returns a positive result
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [php.net/manual/mysqli.query.php](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.query.php), mysqli_query will:

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

You should for you next question specify what you mean by **positive result**. But this code will see if there was an error, if the query returned an empty set, and so on... (I have not tried to run the code)

```php
$result = mysqli_query($cxn,"[query]");
if ($result === FALSE) {
    echo "There was an error";
}
else if ($result === TRUE) {
    echo "The query was successful (a query that didn't return anything)";
}
else if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "The result is empty"
}
else {
    echo '$result contains data';
}
```